# jquery Option Function Should Work Separately

Tags: jquery

I've written this jquery function and want to work separately.

```
$(function(){
    $('.otherreason').hide();
    $('.inqPurpose').change(function() {
        if($(this).find('option:selected').val() == "Other"){
            $('.otherreason').show();
        }else{
            $('.otherreason').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

This html code repeat 4 times in a form tag and when I click any other option field all html work together and I want work it separately

```
<select class="inqPurpose formField" name="how2" id="how2">
    <option>Sales</option>
    <option>Services</option>
    <option>Corporate Partnership</option>
    <option>Corporate Trade Show</option>
    <option>Requesting Product Samples for Trade Show or Event</option>
    <option>Website Feedback</option>
    <option value="Other">Other (Please Specify)</option>
</select>

<input class="formField otherreason" type="text" placeholder="Other Reason" size="53" maxlength="300" />
```

Comment: Are each pair of `.inqPurpose` and `.otherreason` grouped in a common wrapping element?

Answer (score 2):

If you have other reason right after the select option you can use .nextAll() and find the first otherreason class

```
$(function(){
    $('.otherreason').hide();
    $('.inqPurpose').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "Other"){
               $(this).nextAll('.otherreason:first').show();
        }else{
           $(this).nextAll('.otherreason:first').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

fiddle demo here http://jsfiddle.net/kgPaY/1/

Comment: To all upvoters, I believe this doesn't address the problem :)

Comment: Dear its working perfectly thank you so much Anton great repsonse